# jQuery check username ability

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

Hello guys im trying to check the availability of the username when u register but i have problem with returning false,true to know must i submit the form

So i made it with 2 vars - result and wait but when i wait the result the page freezes

```
function checkUser( u ) {
    var wait = true,result;
    $.ajax({
        url: "register.php",
        data: "Available=" + u.val(),
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function(Answer){
            if(Answer == "Taken"){
                result = false;
                updateTips("Потребителското име е заето!");
            } else{
                result = true;
            }
            wait = false;
        }
    });
    while(wait){}
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what is var wait = true,result;?

Comment: var wait = true,result; what is this?

Comment: @jhonraymos that line should work, but the while loop is risky

Comment: its the same as var wait = true; var result;

Comment: @AndreyTsarev Well I feel like an idiot :)

Comment: @Dave just declaring vars in one line, same as if you did var wait=true and var result;

Comment: I've seen var a,b = 0; but never var a = 0, b;

Comment: @AndreyTsarev, show your markup

Comment: why is this in a loop? it should be connected to an event , like type in a username , fire the event , either by blur or click or something - then check it once and return a message , you have an endless loop while the username is taken , assuming the code is working properly

Comment: whit this loop im trying to achieve the js to wait until the page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of that ugly while loop, and add this property to your ajax call:

```
async: false
```

Comment: Please explain me what this does

Comment: It makes the ajax call synchronous, that means that it will wait any further action until the request is complete

Comment: Man you are absolutely awesome...So many peoples trying to help me and you make just one small post and it makes best work

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, note that success property will be deprecated, so try to use .done() instead


"Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead." [from jQuery site]

Answer (score 2):

Yikes.

You dont need to put that in a while loop. As you are bombarding the server with AJAX requests and also will freeze the JS on the client.

Remove the While loop and call the function.

```
function checkUser( u ) {
    $.ajax({
            url: "register.php",
            data: "Available=" + u.val(),
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            success: function(Answer){
                if(Answer == "Taken"){
                     alert("USERNAME TAKEN");
                }
                else{
                    $('#myform').submit();
                }

            }


         });
   }
```

To call it,

```
<input type="submit" onclick="checkUser(data); return false;" />
```

Or, preferred method as suggested by DarkWater

```
<form onsubmit="checkUser(data); return false;">

</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean with call the function?wich funtion?I need the loop to wait until i got the result because i load page to check the username

Comment: You've added a callback event in the JS (The success: part) That will fire when it returns a result. You don't need to worry about that part.

Comment: Yes but the function must return true or false - i cant return while im in event

Comment: No it doesnt need to return true or false. Infact it cant because you cant tell how quick the response will take from the AJAX request. Check the update for form submission

Comment: but your answer code is something that i already know i need to return something so i make the while to wait until the pages load...When you tell me i dont need while, then can u tell me how to wait until the page load

Comment: See the update? You return false on the button click by default. You then call the function, when the function gets a response from the server. It either submits the form or alerts the user that the username is taken.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17620/discussion-between-liamb-and-andrey-tsarev)

Comment: You can also use `<form onsubmit="..." ...>` instead of putting an onclick on the submit button. What if the user presses enter?

Comment: I generate my button with jquery.I am new to jquery and i think i cant add onsubmit

Comment: Try not to use inline js, (atleast with jQuery)

Comment: @Jashwant Normally I'd agree but Im trying to keep it straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple jquery `GET()` function to make a ajax post

```
function checkUser( u ) {
 $.get("register.php?availabe="+u.val(),function(data){
   if(data=="1")
  {  // echo 1 if username is available
        $("form").submit();
  }  //else it would not be submited 
    }) 
}
```

Comment: can i make return because i need it if i return true it allows the form to be submitted else it dont allow

Comment: @AndreyTsarev see the edited answer .Ajax function doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope this will work

```
// assume myForm is your form element id.
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var formEle = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: "register.php",
    data: "Available=" + u.val(),
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    success: function(Answer){
        if(Answer == "Taken"){
            updateTips("Потребителското име е заето!");
        } else {
           formEle.unbind("submit").submit();
        }
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: I added alert(); to Answer == 'Taken' and when i enter Already Used username it dont alert anything

Comment: Humm @AndreyTsarev can you try and see what is back from sever. Can you post just remove all the implementation inside and just alert  success:function(Answer) { alert(Answer); }. It will give you view where you might be wronge

Comment: The main idea here is e.preventDefault(); will prevent your form to submit on default condition. and allow to execute rest of the jQuery code. then later on formEle.unbind("submit").submit(); is used to submit the form you want. so basically when you do e.preventDefault(); for any form.submit then your form does not submit unless you explicitly submit that form from your code.

Comment: Yep im sure that it responses but they already helped me when i add async: false to the ajax